# Do I need to learn CSS if I want to use Bootstrap with Django?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to build a website with Django, and I see in tutorials that Bootstrap is often used, which seems to me like a "ready to use bundle of CSS stuff".
Being completely new to web development, and having a very basic knowledge of HTML, do I need to learn CSS for me to be able to use Bootstrap with Django?

Comment: Bootstrap will give you an option to use prepared styles, but i still advise you to learn the basics. Without basic knowledge, it will be unnecessarily harder for you to use bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You technically don't need to learn CSS at all if you're using Bootstrap but that will limit what you can do if you don't. I'd advise checking out the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) on how to get started with it and go from there.

I won't dump all sorts of links to tutorial sites as there is far too many, however CSS Tricks has a great [almanac](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/) which will help you understand what different CSS properties do.

Make sure you stick to one thing first and make sure you're comfortable with that before moving onto something else. Make sure you can do some basic things with CSS, then move onto more complex things in HTML etc. Bootstrap is very useful though if you're new because it'll have a lot of it done for you.

It'll mainly let you just drop pre-made classes into a template to get a UI setup pretty quickly without many headaches along the way. If you're stuck with anything, check the [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) tag if you get stuck. There's loads of resources there as well. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest if you know the css you can customize you theme as you required.
Or else there is no requirment to kmow css for use bootstrap.
I think you cma freely use bootstrap without know css.